# How to get the return value of a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure and I want to obtain the value that it returns:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExistsItemID]
    @ItemID uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT ItemID FROM Discounts WHERE ItemID = @ItemID))
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0
    END
END
```

And in C# I have the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(scheduleConnection.ConnectionString))
{
    sqlCon.Open();

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("ExistsItemID", scheduleConnection);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();

    SqlParameter returno = new SqlParameter();
    returno.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    int valor = returno.Value;
}
```

But it has not worked for me, how can I get the value of the stored procedure? First of all, thanks

Comment: You need to assign the parameters **before** you execute the statement.

Comment: Add a variable for OUT : @ItemID uniqueidentifier out.

Comment: [Return data from a stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15)  (10 minutes to read)

Comment: @marc_s what's readability? :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand: it's **important** ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the parameter to the command before executing it.  Use the `Add` method on the `Parameters` collection.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(scheduleConnection.ConnectionString))
{
    sqlCon.Open();

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("ExistsItemID", scheduleConnection);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter returno = new SqlParameter();
    returno.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(returno);

    sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        
    int valor = returno.Value;
}
```